# File upload with react, nodeJS multer doesn't work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, multer

i made this function, which takes the **file** value ( image ) from the **file** state and send it to upload route, through **FormData** object

```
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
```

```
  const submitPost = async (e) => {
  ...
    e.preventDefault();
    if (file) {
      const data = new FormData();
      const fileName = `${Date.now()}${file.name}`;
      data.append("name", fileName);
      data.append("file", file);
      try {
        await fetch("http://localhost:8000/upload", {
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          },
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
        });
        // window.location.reload();
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  };
```

the **file** value in the **file state** is coming from form file input

```
        <form className="postOptions" onSubmit={submitPost}>
          <div className="postAreaBot">
            <label htmlFor="file" className="downloadImg">
              <AddAPhotoIcon className="postIcon" />
              <span>Image</span>
            </label>
            <input
              type="file"
              accept=".png,.jpeg,.jpg"
              onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
              id="file"
              style={{ display: "none" }}
            ></input>
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Post</button>
        </form>
```

and then sending the **file** value to this route for upload on folder **images** inside folder **public** using **multer** and **path**

```
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/images")));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "public/images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, req.body.name);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
app.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  try {
    return res.status(200).json("File uploaded successfully");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

but the image is not being uploaded

**what have i tried**

i tested the route using **file.originalName** for **postman** instead of **file.req.body** and the route does indeed works and images are being uploaded successfully, i also checked the values **name** and **file** in the **data** object and it appends it successfully, i can't see what is the problem, why it doesn't upload the image file through the react **fetch** request?

Comment: You have to change your header to `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` when you send your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the JSON.stringify. And change your content type, like the example below:

```
    await fetch("http://localhost:8000/upload", {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
    });
```

Comment: obs: you actually don't need to specify the content type in the header, your browser will do that for you ;)